# How to compile SASS files using dart sass in C/C++ language?

Tags: sass, dart, libsass

Is it possible to compile sass files using dart sass in my server written in C++? If so, Could you please guide me?

Comment: You can start a process from C++ that executes Dart sass.

Comment: Are you suggesting to create a process and give the cli command that needs to be executed? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Yes, that's my suggestion.

Comment: Is there a way to access to access its API and compile it instead of using terminal commands?  @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: I don't think so. I'd create an issue in the SASS GitHub repo.

Comment: Incase if am using libsass, I should be writing a wrapper around it and use it right?

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/libsass#sassc seems to be that. I'm not a C/C++ developer.